# AWS lambda PostgreSQL RDS Connections limit issue

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds

The back-end is for mobile app.

I`m facing an issue that my lambda return
"error: remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections"

It will happen in around 2k active users open the app when we push a notification then press it and open the app.

So it should be lot of user calling api at the same time.
At this time ,the error comes out.

For now, im using db.r4.large
Is it need to upgrade it?
Any suggestion can help on this?

Please help,  thanks a lot

i have check on the Performance Insights from AWS RDS

[Here is the screen cap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtple.png)

[This is the status in normal time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mpplj.png)

Comment: Sounds like there are too many open connections to your database. This happens because a lot of Lambdas are started (especially if you have a lot of concurrent users). Those Lambdas open a connection but never close it. Check out the Lambda RDS Proxy feature. This should fix this issue: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-rds-proxy-with-aws-lambda/

Comment: You should use a *connection pool*.